# How to create Navigation Menu JSON dynamically from array of routes

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking

Need the below given input in the given output format. How can I use a brute force approach and dynamic programming approach for this? I tried but could not get any clue how to proceed.

**INPUT**

```
[
    "Application/Calendar",
    "Application/Chrome",
    "Application/Webstrom",
    "Application/Photoshop",
    "Application/firefox",
    "Documents/Material-UI/src/index.js",
    "Documents/Material-UI/src/tree-view.js"
]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Application",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Calendar",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Chrome",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Webstrom",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Photoshop",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "name": "firefox",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Documents",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Material-UI",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "src",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "index.js",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "tree-view.js",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach:

```js
let category = [
    "Application/Calendar",
    "Application/Chrome",
    "Application/Webstrom",
    "Application/Photoshop",
    "Application/firefox",
    "Documents/Material-UI/src/index.js",
    "Documents/Material-UI/src/tree-view.js"
].map(str => str.split("/"));

let result = [];
for (const names of category) names.reduce((children, name) => {
    let next = children.find(item => item.name == name);
    if (!next) children.push(next = { name, children: [] })
    return next.children;
}, result)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey Nur, Thanks for such a quick response. Yes, I tried but could not get solution and it's never my intention to get the solution without trying. Even after posting the question I got the response but comparing to your solution that is useless. Your solution is very impressive. Thanks!

Comment: does it answer you question ?

Comment: Hey Nur, of course, it did. Your solution is working as expected.

Comment: @VivekSingh: I think Nur was suggesting that you could accept the answer. To "accept", click the tick/check mark adjacent to the answer. It is not mandatory to do it, but it is encouraged. It is a nice way to thank the person who helped you, and it signposts the answer as helpful for future readers.